# Creating and Assigning variables in a loop

Tags: python

```
list = ["PIG", "DOG", "CAT"]
```

Was wondering how can I iterrate through the list and assigned each item as a new variable? Ideally i would want to create these variables and initialize it inside a loop.

```
Expected outcome:
var1 = "PIG"
var2 = "CAT"
var3 = "DOG"
```

Comment: This looks like an *XY Problem*. Why do you need separate variables for the list elements instead of accessing them by index?

Comment: @CristiFati Or use a *dictionary* instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this -

```py
ls=["PIG", "DOG", "CAT"]
cntr=1
for i in ls:
    locals()['var'+str(cntr)] = i
    cntr += 1
```

You will get output as:

```
var1 = "PIG"
var2 = "CAT"
var3 = "DOG"
```

Comment: Accessing `locals` like this is bad practice and likely to lead to buggy behaviour for the OP down the line. Use a dictionary

Comment: In [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), note the "Answer Well-Asked Questions" section, and therein the bullet point regarding questions that "have been asked and answered many times before". That's particularly important here, where the *best* answer is arguably not a literal one, but one that instructs the user to store their `PIG`, `DOG` and `CAT` values as keys in a dictionary instead. An already-answered copy of the question will already have *both* the literal answer and the best-practice one present, providing the OP with more context and choice.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - Makes sense!